# Hard fork versions

Tags: hard-fork

Where can I find explanation about the different versions(from 1 to 9)?
Is there a way to change the version to RingCT's version on testnet (started from scratch - block 0)  without causing troubles with constructing transactions or receiving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a table with some information about the protocol versions in the *README* file of the Monero source code (https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md).

Extract from the table:

```
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
|   Block |       Date | Protocol | Minimum   | Details                              |
|  height |            | version  | software  |                                      |
|         |            |          | version   |                                      |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1009827 | 2016-03-22 | v2       | v0.9.4    | Allow only >= ringsize 3,            |
|         |            |          |           | blocktime = 120 seconds,             |
|         |            |          |           | fee-free blocksize 60 kb             |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1141317 | 2016-09-21 | v3       | v0.9.4    | Splits coinbase into denominations   |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1220516 | 2017-01-05 | v4       | v0.10.1   | Allow normal and RingCT transactions |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1288616 | 2017-04-15 | v5       | v0.10.3.0 | Adjusted minimum blocksize and fee   |
|         |            |          |           | algorithm                            |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1400000 | 2017-09-16 | v6       | v0.11.0.0 | Allow only RingCT transactions,      |
|         |            |          |           | allow only >= ringsize 5             |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1546000 | 2018-04-06 | v7       | v0.12.0.0 | Cryptonight variant 1,               |
|         |            |          |           | ringsize >= 7,                       |
|         |            |          |           | sorted inputs                        |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1685555 | 2018-10-18 | v8       | v0.13.0.0 | max transaction size at half the     |
|         |            |          |           | penalty free block size,             |
|         |            |          |           | bulletproofs enabled,                |
|         |            |          |           | cryptonight variant 2,               |
|         |            |          |           | fixed ringsize 11                    |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
| 1686275 | 2018-10-19 | v9       | v0.13.0.0 | bulletproofs required                |
|---------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------------------------|
```

The block heights for protocol upgrades are defined in the file *src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp*. You can probably change the heights of the testnet protocol upgrades for your personal testnet, but I have never tried and there might be some other things to change for things to work well.